# Cassandra Node Fails on Batch Insert

Tags: cassandra, cql

When we do batch insert into cassandra with batch size 40000 rows. Suddenly the node fails and the cassandra process is stopped then i should run cassandra -R command again. Do you have any idea about this problem?
Thanks for your kindness

Comment: This question have no relation to the `batch-file` tag. Please, review the purpose of any tag before you include it...

Comment: "Do you have any idea about this problem?"  Yes. Simply put, don't do that.  Run each insert separately.

Comment: Also, I'm upvoting this question because I feel it's important for other new users to see what happens when you try this.

Answer (score 2):

Batches in Cassandra aren't the same as batches in traditional databases.  Most probably that you put data for different partitions into the same batch, and coordinator node is overloaded with data that it's trying to handle the request.

You need to use batches wisely - use them only to batch entries with the same partition key. If the data belongs to different partitions, just use async API - it will be much faster.

You can read more about good & wrong use of batches in the [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useBatch.html).